# Proving 1-2-1 Correspondence with half planes

Tags: geometry

Given two points, $A$ and $B$, let $H$ be one of the half-planes of the line connecting $A$ and $B$. Let E be a point in the half-plane $H$ such that the function f goes from the angle $\angle BAE$ $\rightarrow$ $(0,180)$ degrees.

Prove F is a 1-1 correspondence

Thanks guys!!

Comment: "One-to-one" is written "1-1", not "1-2-1".

Comment: What efforts have you made to solve the problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Honestly not sure how to post what i've done so far